# JavaScript Row Transposition Cipher - how to convert key into column numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encryption

I am having some trouble converting the letters from the key into their alphabetical order in Row Transposition Cipher.

If, for example, we take the **word "fruit" as our key**, it should translate to the following sequence of numbers: "***6(f) 18(r) 21(u) 9(i) 20(t)***"

I managed to achieve that using this function:

```
function filterKey(key) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        var c = key.charCodeAt(i);
        result.push((c - 65) % 32);
    }
    return result;
}
```

My question is : How can I convert the above sequence of numbers into column numbers?

Like this: **"6(f) 18(r) 21(u) 9(i) 20(t)"** --> **"1(f) 3(r) 5(u) 2(i) 4(t)"**

Comment: What are column numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want to do this *inside* the function or after the result was returned.

Either way, the following should do the job:

```js
var key = "fruit";
var result = key.split("").map(function(x) {return (x.charCodeAt(0) - 65) % 32}); // (one-liner for your function)
var sorted = result.slice(0).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
var columnNumbers = result.map(function(x) {
    var index = sorted.indexOf(x);
    sorted[index] = 0; // reset value in case of duplicate chars
    return index + 1;
});
console.log(columnNumbers);
```

Note that this is designed to deal with duplicate letters in the key.

For example `"froot"` will output `[1, 4, 2, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Map characters to alphabetic indices

   `[].map.call ("fruit", c => c.charCodeAt (0)^96)`
   `//[6, 18, 21, 9, 20]`

To Transpose your message with a given key

```
function trnsps (key, msg) {
 let {map}=[],_l,_n=0;
 //Build the lookup indices from the key
 let _key = key 
     .split('') //Split the key
     .sort()    //Sort it alphabetically
     .map ((l,i) => key.indexOf (l)) //map it to the original index
     .map (n => {
           let r=_l==n?n+ ++_n:n+(_n=0); 
           _l=n;
           return r
      }) //increase the index for every consecutive character
 //Map the alphabetical indices to characters
 msg = map.call (msg, c => typeof c=="number"?String.fromCharCode(c^96):c)
//Encode the input with the given key
 let enc = map.call (msg, (c,i) => (
  msg[_key[i]] 
));
//Map the message to column indexes
 return msg.map (c => -~enc.indexOf (c));
}
```

```js
trnsps("fruit", "fruit");
trnsps ("fruit", [6,18,21,9,20])
trnsps ("frooot", "fruit")
console.log (
    trnsps ("froot", [6,18,21,9,20])
)
```

```html
<script>
    function trnsps (key, msg) {
     let {map}=[],_l,_n=0;
     //Build the lookup indices from the key
     let _key = key 
         .split('') //Split the key
         .sort()    //Sort it alphabetically
         .map ((l,i) => key.indexOf (l)) //map it to the original index
         .map (n => {
               let r=_l==n?n+ ++_n:n+(_n=0); 
               _l=n;
               return r
          }) //increase the index for every consecutive character
     //Map the alphabetical indices to characters
     msg = map.call (msg, c => typeof c=="number"?String.fromCharCode(c^96):c)
    //Encode the input with the given key
     let enc = map.call (msg, (c,i) => (
      msg[_key[i]] 
    ));
    //Map the message to column indexes
     return msg.map (c => -~enc.indexOf (c));
    }
</script>
```